# How to tell if a user on a site has a static IP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Is there a good way to be able to tell if a user has a static IP?  I want to be able to ID which users that come to my site have static IPs.

Comment: <s>Belongs on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).</s> Oh woops, didn't see the php tag... Curses.

Comment: as below no, and an ip may change from one to the other, what where you trying to achieve by knowing this is in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

No there is not. This is information that is only found on that network.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, there's no guaranteed way to tell whether a given IP address is statically or dynamically allocated.

You might be able to get 90% of the way there by leveraging the efforts of some of the anti-spam organizations out there -- for example,
[Spamhaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/), the "Policy Block List", is a database of IP address ranges that have been identified by the responsible ISPs as addresses that should not be direct sources of legitimate email.  I suspect that the bulk of this list is going to be residential end users on dialup or consumer broadband services.  This is only a heuristic -- I'm sure
there are static IP blocks in the PBL, and probably plenty of dynamic IP addresses that
*aren't* on it, but it's about as close as you're going to get without knowing each
IP range owner's allocation policy.

Answer (score 2):

If user turns on maintenance mode the system should record the user ip and from that point only allow that ip to enter, untill maintenance mode is turned off.

Above was what I needed for a website.
Below is what I used:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION[last_ip]!==$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR])
    {
    $_SESSION[ips] = (!is_numeric($_SESSION[ips])) ? 1 : $_SESSION[ips] + 1;
    $_SESSION[last_ip] = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];
    }
if ($_SESSION[ips]===1) { echo "Static IP"; }
else { echo "Dynamic IP"; }
?>
```

According to the replies posted (ages ago, sry 'bout that) it is close to impossible to achieve this.
For me it works... unless I don't get something.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache client will be delivered a packet that just tells you what the IP address is.

You can keep track of IPs and see if they are being used repeatedly, but static versus dynamic is negotiated by the network he is connecting to and not your website.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, only via empirical evidence, same IP turning up repetitively - even then that's no guarantee it's the same user, unless it is matched to a user account or cookie, etc.

Whether an IP is static or dynamically allocated is not something that can be queried.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to detect the presence of NAT, because NAT "mangles" the packets. I'm not sure how NAT works exactly, I think it's based on the source port. But I think NAT might mangle other parts of the TCP header like time-to-live in recognizable ways. Not that NAT is a 100% guarantee that they have a dynamic IP, but it is often used with DHCP.

Answer (score -1):

it is possible by applet .

You can create a java applet and get the ip of the local computer and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and math both and can identify whether it is having static or dynamic ip

Comment: I think you're confusing dynamic/static IP addresses with whether the client device is behind a router or not...

Comment: Mr Bergius I am suggesting to fetch the static ip through the php script and through the java applet get the system ip and math both ip , if both are equal then it means that the page is opened by the static ip system 
Got my point ?